# SSL certificate verification can be turned off in Postman - how to do the same thing in Retrofit (Android)?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

In Postman I can make working API calls by turning off certificate verification in the preferences, how can I (just for testing) turn it off in Retrofit?

When I try to use the appropritate certificate I get the error:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

When I try to create a trust manager that trusts all certs I get the error:
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname not verified

What is Postman doing to make these calls work, and how can I replicate it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this codes

```
builder.hostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier());


public static HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier() {
    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    return hostnameVerifier;
}
```